# Hibernate :many to many doesn't work

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm working on a many to many relationship with hibernate

here are my tables in the data-base :

table : Service
table : Pays
and the join table : service-pays

I have 2 entities : Service and Pays
here is my code:

```
  public class Service implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idService;
    private String nomService;
    private Set<Pays> payses = new HashSet<Pays>();
        // getters & setters
         ....
  }
  public class Pays implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idPays;
    private String nomPays;
    private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<Service>(0);
        // getters & setters
         ....
  }
```

the mapping fils are:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="pckg">
   <class name="pckg.Service" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true"  table="service" catalog="database" lazy="false" >
        <id name="idService" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_service" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomService" />
        <set name="countries" table="service_pays" lazy="true"
            inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="id_service" />
            <many-to-many column="id_pays" class="pckg.Pays" />
        </set>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping package="pckg">
   <class name="pckg.Pays" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true"  table="service" catalog="database" lazy="false" >
     <id name="idPays" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_pays" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomPays" />
        <set name="ser" table="service_pays" lazy="true"
              cascade="save-update" >
            <key column="id_pays" />
            <many-to-many column="id_service" class="pckg.Service" />
        </set>


</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

my methode to save the service:

```
   Pays p1= new Pays("France");
      Pays p2=new Pays("Italy");
      Set<Pays> list-pays=new HashSet<Pays>();
      list-pays.add(p1);
      list-pays.add(p2);

      Service service=new Service();
      service.setNomService("nomService"); 
      service.setCountries(list-pays);
      serviceBo.saveService(service);
```

Here is serviceBo.saveService:

```
  public class ServiceBoImp implements ServiceBo ,Serializable{


    ServiceDao serviceDao;

    //getter & setter of serviceDao


    @Override
    public void saveService(Service sited) {

        serviceDao.saveService(sited);
    }
   }
```

and here is ServiceDao

```
public class ServiceDaoImp extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ServiceDao ,Serializable {

    @Override
    public void saveService(ServiceDsite s) {

        getHibernateTemplate().setCheckWriteOperations(false);

        getHibernateTemplate().save(s);

    } 
  }
```

the problem is that when i save a service with its Set ,the service is saved correctly but without Pays which means the join table is always empty

Comment: can you post `serviceBo.saveService`?

Comment: @jhadesdev I've posted serviceBo and serviceDao

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that service.getPays() is marked with `inverse="true"`. This means that Hibernate should ignore this side of the relation and track only the other.

Try to move the inverse=true to the other side of the relation, and then the cascade save should work.

Comment: I've moved inverse="true" from service to pays but it still not working